# CSS: Background-attachment: fixed doesnt work in android

Tags: android, html, css

I need to set `background-attachment: fixed` to several backgrounds on [this page](http://studioguava.by/) (russian text, but you'll see all bugs, if open it on Android Browser), but it's won't work! It's very important for me, I search how to do it, but it's work for one bg, not for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the dev tools in Chrome, your `smartmobile.css` you needs some changes on the main container divs:

```
.ct-general {
  background-attachment: scroll; /* Change this to fixed, line 1 */
}

.ct-catalog {
  background-attachment: scroll; /* change to fixed, remove other declarations, line 4 */
}

.ct-schema {
  background-attachment: scroll; /* change to fixed, line 9 */
}

.ct-sravn {
  background: url('../images/bg_wins.png') !important;
  background-size: auto !important;
  background-attachment: scroll !important; /*change to fixed, line 12 */
}

.ct-clients {
  background: url('../images/clients_bg.png') !important;
  background-size: auto !important;         /* change to cover to fill the space */
  background-attachment: scroll !important; /* change to fixed, 18 */
}
```

This will match your desktop styles on mobile now.

Comment: but `background-attachment: fixed` don't show backgrounds at all

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm testing this method and it's displaying correctly for mobile (Android specific) when I look at the page. What's not working right?

Comment: I change `scroll` to `fixed`, check out. I check it on HTC One M8 (android 4.4.2), and it's don't work. p.s. check out horizontal orientation.

Comment: I'm testing all this using the Chrome dev tools, which emulates mobile browsers. I've not had compatibility problems with it before, so I tend to trust it...I still see the backgrounds on my Samsung GS3, though.

Comment: now **all** backgrounds, that I changed are invisible.

Comment: clear your cache on your smartphone, and on chrome dev tools all will working.